# Changing menu item visibility after selecting one

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have two menu items, with id `R.id.start` and `R.id.stop`. At the beginning only "start: is visible. Now I want to change visibility of both of them when any of them are selected.

I tried to do this by calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and then on `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)` I changed visibility. The problem is that I'm getting empty `menu`. This is probably because `menu` wants to recreate and I have empty `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` and I'm not creating one, after it was created before.

Of course I could recreate it, but it is not needed. Is there any way to tell android to call `onPrepareOptionsMenu` but without calling `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but if you are saying you don't want the menu to display after the second option is made invisible can't you just return false from your onPrepareOptionsMenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont actually need onPrepareOptionsMenu I used to use that and the results weren't as pretty.

In your class make an integer(e.g. mine is called activated) and change the integer values whenever you want like so and then invalidate your options menu :

```
onClick(View v)
{
     activated=1;
     getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Now in your options menu, check for the value of the integer, clear the menu then inflate accordingly(you can inflate as many as you want) :

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
 {
     if(activated==1)
     {
         menu.clear();  //this makes all the menus invisible
         //my menu is called secret
         getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secret, menu);
         //you mgiht want to inflate another one here    
         activated=0;
     }
     else if(activated==2)
     {
            //etc
     }        
     else
     {
            //etc
     }
 }
```